# Identifying Punctuation Marks in a string in VB

Tags: string, vb.net, translation, punctuation

I wont say i am totally new to VB but I am not expert either. I have this uni task where I am writing a pig latin program. I have got everything sorted but missing out on a part where punctuation is involved. I am rearranging character in a word based or vowels and consonants but i also need to make sure that any punctuation marks stay as it is, for instance. bat will be changed to atbway but in case it had a period at the end i.e. bat. the output has to be atbway.

This also applies to instances where a word has "" as they need to stay as it is with the words between them rearranged. I can put a function in place to check the first and last character of a word but how do i check if these characters are punctuations ?

Comment: The `Char` structure has a number of `Shared` methods for identifying the type of a character, including `Char.IsPunctuation`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was able to create a function to recreate the words with punctuation marks.